# Groovydoc produces blank documents

Tags: groovy, javadoc, groovydoc

I'm writing a class in Groovy, and I want to generate Groovydoc for it (from the command line). In my class, I've written documentation for the methods like this:

```
/**
 * Returns blah blah blah
*/
def getFoo(){
    ...
}
```

But when I run `groovydoc -classpath C:\groovyStuff\ -d . *.groovy`

It generates the HTML template, but no actual content.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Are the `*.groovy` files in the current directory when you run the command?

Comment: No, they're in the groovyStuff directory. I'm trying to run the command on the *.groovy files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the root of your source tree is `c:\groovyStuff\` you can use something like this...

```
groovydoc -sourcepath c:\groovyStuff -d . com.somepackage
```

The `-d .` is a little peculiar because that is going to put the generated files in the current directory.  That is what you used in your example but maybe you want something like `-d output` or something similar.

Does that help?

Comment: sourcepath or classpath? I used http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/05/documenting-groovy-with-groovydoc.html as an example. The sample command is toward the middle of the page. I didn't get the impression the files needed to be part of a package either.

Comment: sourcepath and classpath are 2 different things.  I meant sourcepath, which is what I typed.  For example, if you have files like `c:\groovyStuff\com\somepackage\Demo.groovy` and `c:\groovyStuff\com\somepackage\Widget.groovy`, the command I show above will generate javadocs for those in the current directory (whatever directory you executed that command from).

Comment: You may or may not need to specify a classpath.  That depends on details of your code which are not represented in the question.

Comment: Okay, it works with sourcepath. I had to specify the name of the class though, *.groovy did not work. Thank you for your help!

groovydoc -sourcepath C:\groovyStuff -d . scriptName.groovy

Answer (score 1):

For Eclipse users, here is a workaround:

1. Go to Project -> Generate Javadoc...
2. In Javadoc command, replace the 'javadoc.exe' path with the 'groovydoc.bat' path.
3. Select the sources to be generated, the visibility and use the standard doclet (I suggest you create a new file src/main/groovydoc and delete src/main/javadoc)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you application consists of Java & Groovy files you can leverage next bash script which lists all java & groovy files in the source directory (even skipping undesired ones)

```
source_files=`find {path-to-your-dir}/ -type f \( \
    \( \
    -name "*.java" \
    -or -name "*.groovy" \
    \) \
    ! \
    \( \
     -name "UndesiredOne.java" \
     -or -name "UndesiredTwo.groovy" \
    \) \
    \)`

groovydoc -verbose --debug -public\
 -d {path-to-your-doc-dir}\
 -doctitle "Title"\
 -header "Header"\
 -footer "Footer"\
 -windowtitle "WindowTitle"\
 $source_files
```